# Is there a way to embed a bookdown document as a blogdown post?

Tags: hugo, bookdown, blogdown

I have created a tutorial using Bookdown (which I think is a great format for it), and am currently in the process of creating a website using Blogdown (hugo-academic theme). I would like to be able to add this tutorial to a tutorials page as a Bookdown post, but I don't know if that's possible.

I'm new to Blogdown, so I haven't been able to find any solutions to this. If it's not possible, is there a way of changing the post link to a hyperlink that takes the user to a published Bookdown file (perhaps to bookdown.org)?

Comment: How about using "Projects" for this? I find it more appropriate than a (blog) post, and there it is easy to link to an external site. It might be possible to to integrate the rendered output from bookdown into blogdown, but that sounds like a lot of hassle.

Comment: @RalfStubner, that seems like it would do what I'm interested in, but when I created a new widget page called "Tutorials", (I copied the project files), it redirects to the project/ directory for the associated projects. What's telling it to look there, as I couldn't see anything in the config or index files?

Comment: Do you have `page_type = "project"` in your `tutorials.md`? You should change this to `page_type = "tutorials"`.

Comment: Yes, and it is in the `content/tutorial/` directory, as I do not want it on the home screen. It is showing the filters specified, just not the documents within `content/tutorial/`

Comment: In order to utilize widgets on other pages than the home page you need to add an `index.md` widget page, c.f. https://sourcethemes.com/academic/docs/managing-content/#create-a-widget-page

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but I have an index page as the documentation suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my point of view it makes more sense to keep the tutorials (written with `bookdown`) separate from the rest of the website (written with `blogdown`). One possible solution is to use the "portfolio" widget together with content that uses `external_link`, similar to how "external projects" work. Since you do not want the tutorials widget on the home page, you need to do the following:

1. Create a directory `content/tutorial` containing directories for every individual tutorial. Each of these directories contains an `index.md` modeled after "external project", i.e. with an `external_link` attribute.
2. Create a second directory `content/tutorials` with an `index.md` widget page, c.f. https://sourcethemes.com/academic/docs/managing-content/#create-a-widget-page
3. Create in the *second* directory a portfolio widget, e.g. by copying `projects.md`, where you set `page_type` to `tutorial` (the name of the *first* directory).

The crucial point is that you need two directories. One for the tutorials and one for the widgets. Full example is on [GitHub](https://github.com/rstub/stackoverflow/commits/master/57415416). Of course, it would make sense to add a link to `/tutorials/` (not `/tutorial/`!) to your sites menu.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks for your help Ralf!