# Is there a way to create 'docs' style internal project post in hugo academic?

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

Following on from [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57415416/is-there-a-way-to-embed-a-bookdown-document-as-a-blogdown-post/57427143#57427143), I was wondering if it is possible to create an internal project post in Blogdown and hugo academic that is structured like a "Courses" document?

My current thought is to create a 'hidden' courses section that can be linked to by a project, however, relative paths like `external_link: "courses/my-example-course"` don't seem to work. I suppose I could provide an https link after publishing, but this seems inefficient.

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried an absolute URL: `external_link: "courses/my-example-course"`?

Comment: @RalfStubner, I have but unfortunately it did not work. I also tried `external_link: "courses/my-example-course/_index.md"` and `external_link: "../../courses/my-example-course` but those also didn't work (including variations without quotation marks).

Comment: That's surprising. It seems to work for me, c.f. https://github.com/rstub/stackoverflow/commits/master/57415416

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that it just wasn't working in the RStudio viewer, which I use instead of Chrome because it is unusably slow on my laptop. It's opening another tab, but that's to be expected with an external link.

The working solution is to use `external_link: /courses/my-example-course`, and it's important to have the first `/`, otherwise it returns a 404 page.